# Is there a way to find the sum of each row? postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say you have a table of n columns like

```
  create table x
     (id integer
      x0 integer,
      x1 integer,
      x2 integer,
      x3 integer,
      .....
      xn integer
      primary key(id)
      )
```

n can be a big number, also you don't know the names of the columns. Let's say you have 50 rows like

```
insert into x (74934,1, 9, 21, 5....16)
insert into x (58496,4, 2, 3, 19....52)
.....
insert into x (10475,48, 245, 8, 71....111)
```

Is there a way to find the sum of each row?
Like 1 + 9 + 21 + 5 +...+ 16 = sum of first row

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: One way or another, you will need to enumerate all the columns names.

Comment: There's a good reason not to use a dynamic number of columns, but a properly normalised schema. You must need to know the names of the columns you want to use.

Comment: Still if you know them, what if there are 300 columns? @Bergi

Comment: @darkis Then spell them out. But yes, that's the reason not to use 300-column tables.

Comment: Maybe you should use a spreadsheet instead.Or SAS, or R, or python.

Answer (score 0):

Using [JSON(B) functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
with t(id, x1, x2, x3) as (values(1,1,2,3),(2,4,5,6))
select
    id,
    (select sum(value::numeric) from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t)) where key like 'x%')
from t;
```