# Postgres: Get Max Length across columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to retrieve a record which has maximum length.

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Column1    | Column2      | Column3
--------------------------------------------
1  |   123456   |   1234       |   12     
2  |   123      |   1234567    |   NULL
```

I want an output like this:

```
ID | Column1    | Column2      | Column3  | Max_Column
---------------------------------------------------------
1  |   123456   |   1234       |   12     |  123456
2  |   123      |   1234567    |   NULL   |  1234567
```

In this case, it's fairly easily to achieve it by using a `CASE` statement. But in the original table, I have more than 20 columns.

I tried using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table but it didn't help much as it is limited to just one column.
I want the query to parse all the columns in one row and return the column with MAX LENGTH.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394062/593144 - just use `max()` instead of `sum()`

Comment: Do you really mean the max **length** in characters, rather than the numeric value? What if you have `0.123456789` and `42` as column values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.*, v.max_col
from t cross join lateral
     (select max(col) as max_col
      from (values (col1), (col2), . . . ) v(col)
     ) v;
```

You can generate the code, if you like, using `information_schema.columns` and either a SQL statement or by copying the column names into a spreadsheet and generating the code there.

Or you can use Postgres's non-standard `greatest()` function:

```
select t.*, greatest(col1, col2, . . .) as max_col
from t;
```

Comment: `select t.*, greatest(col1, col2, ...) as max_col from t;` is much simpler.

Comment: @Abelisto . . . You are right.  It is one of Postgres rare flagrant violations of the standard.  Those functions should return `NULL` if *any* values are `NULL`.

Comment: Hm. Not sure about standard, but it is corresponding to `max()`/`min()`behavior.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you both! Another follow-up to this: What if I want to get the column with the greatest STRPOS(col, ' ')?

Edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: @Garfield: please do not change your question to a completely different one, once you get an answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Apologies! Will create a new question then.